# Counting words from the web - Python

Tags: python, web, count

Update (I need to rephrase this)

I'm trying to do the following:

Write a program that **downloads** and counts the total number of words in 'http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt'.

However, I'm not sure how to do that. I have the following working code:

```
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt')
for line in fhand:
    print(line.decode().strip())
```

The above will download the 4 lines. I need to be able to download it **as well as** get the count which is 33.

Is there a way to do both tasks at the same time within the code? My professor gave me the following:

```
import urllib.parse, urllib.request, urllib.error
import re



url = "http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt"
```

I feel there's a clue where I have to use re but not sure how to apply it to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is count how many times every individual word appears, you can sum the number of items that you in every line when you use the .split() method like:

```
counts = 0
for line in fhand.readlines():
    words = line.decode().split()
    counts += len(words)

print(counts)
```

Comment: to make the answer more readable could you provide input and the output of this code?

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach using container datatypes *Counter*  https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

```
import urllib.request
from collections import Counter
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt') as response:
    words = response.read().decode('utf-8').split()
c = Counter(words)
# optionally
print(c.most_common())
```

Comment: That's a pretty good approach! Is there a way to do that though using re and getting the count of 33 (the actual count) from this?

Comment: `sum(c.values())`